# checkSelfPermission returns false if user has chosen "While using the app" optin

Tags: android, permissions

To check locations permission, I call

```
private fun isLocationPermissionAllowed(): Boolean {
    val locationPermission = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
    } else {
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    }

    return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        app,
        locationPermission
    ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
}
```

Problem is that this code piece will return `false` if user chooses "While using the app".
This function is called on apps startup, meaning, that it will ask permission all the time when app has been re-opened. Is this normal behaviour? I thought that `checkSelfPermission` will return false if user has chosen `DENY` and true for the rest of the cases.

Comment: maybe the system needs time on app startup to grant it for the user. Did you verify that your method returns true if the user grants it? When do you make this check? To test it, try to execute your method with some delay, e.g. 10 seconds, just to see what is happening.

Comment: what is your target api level? Are these permissions added to the manifest?

Comment: this same issue is occuring in android 10. Please provide some explanation....

Comment: any help please about this issue...

Comment: any help please about this issue...